# Interact with Facebook, from AS3 using the Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, actionscript, sdk

I'm triyng to use the Facebook **AS3** API but it's actually inconsistent. Frustrating.

I'm  thinking to use the Javascript SDK, from an Flash/AS3 based app, using the `ExternalInterface` object, and the `addCallback` method.

Is a good idea to try to do this? anyone have any advice for me?

Any comments on it will be appreciated!
Thanks.
Mike

Comment: I've used the AS3 API successfully w/o any issues for a game with 800k+ users.  What exactly are you finding "inconsistent"?

Comment: Hi Madbreaks, can you explain me how do you implement the AS3 API? With "inconsistent" I want to say that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work, and some functionalities sometimes works and other misteriously doesn't work. Please if you have an example of working code?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any sample code I can share. What I recall though is that we had an issue w/ the ExternalInterface callbacks at one point.  Pay particular attention to how you're implementing those.  Once we got that issue squared away we did not run into any further issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this method rather than the AS3 api in several of my facebook games without any issues. The facebook javascript api is fairly straight-forward and interfacing with it from my flash app has worked great.

Comment: Thanks to reply Dean! I have used this method and works fine for me too.